# Pandas select matching multi index with different number of levels

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with 3 index levels:

```
       d
a b c   
1 9 4  1
2 8 2  4
3 7 5  2
4 6 4  5
5 5 6  3
6 4 5  6
7 3 7  4
8 2 6  7
9 1 8  5
```

and I have a multi index object with only 2 levels:

```
MultiIndex([(1, 9),
            (2, 8),
            (3, 7),
            (4, 6),
            (9, 1)],
           names=['a', 'b'])
```

How can I select the entries on the data frame that match this multi index?

Toy code:

```py
import pandas

df1 = pandas.DataFrame(
    dict(
        a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
        b = [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1],
        c = [4,2,5,4,6,5,7,6,8],
        d = [1,4,2,5,3,6,4,7,5],
    )
).set_index(['a','b','c'])
select_this = multi_idx = pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7), (4, 6), (9, 1)], names=['a', 'b'])

selected = df1.loc[select_this]

print(select_this)
print(df1)
print(selected)
```

which produces `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,2) (3,) (5,2)`.

What I want to do can be achieved with

```py
selected = df1.reset_index('c').loc[select_this].set_index('c', append=True)
```

However, this forces me to do this extra `reset_index` and then `set_index`. I want to avoid this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter different levels by [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
lvl = df1.index.names.difference(multi_idx.names)
out = df1[df1.index.droplevel(lvl).isin(multi_idx)]
print (out)
       d
a b c   
1 9 4  1
2 8 2  4
3 7 5  2
4 6 4  5
9 1 8  5
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
multi_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7), (4, 6), (9, 1)], names=['a', 'b'])

out = df.reset_index(level='c')

m = ((out.index.get_level_values('a').isin(multi_idx.get_level_values('a'))) &
     (out.index.get_level_values('b').isin(multi_idx.get_level_values('b'))))

df[m]
```

Output:

```
       d
a b c   
1 9 4  1
2 8 2  4
3 7 5  2
4 6 4  5
9 1 8  5
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using `.merge`:

```py
out = pd.merge(df1, df2.query("e==5"), left_index=True, right_index=True)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
       d  e
a b c      
1 9 4  1  5
2 8 2  4  5
3 7 5  2  5
4 6 4  5  5
9 1 8  5  5
```

Comment: This is nice in that it does not need to hard code index levels names, but it relies on having the other data frame, which is there only because of the way I constructed the example. I will now modify it because I am looking for a solution using only a multi index.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're trying to index a *3-levels* DataFrame with *2-levels* object.

You need to [`droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.droplevel.html) to ensure they have the same shape :

```
out = df1.loc[df1.index.droplevel(2).isin(select_this)]
```

Output :

```
print(out)

       d
a b c   
1 9 4  1
2 8 2  4
3 7 5  2
4 6 4  5
9 1 8  5
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is with [pyjanitor's select](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.select.select) function, where you can either pass a list of tuples, or a dictionary (the keys in the dictionary are the index levels, while the values are the values for that particular level):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
```

First option - list of tuples:

```py
mapper = [entry for entry in select_this]
df1.select(rows=mapper)
       d
a b c   
1 9 4  1
2 8 2  4
3 7 5  2
4 6 4  5
9 1 8  5
```

Second option - a dictionary:

```py
mapping = {key:select_this.get_level_values(key) for key in select_this.names}
df1.select(rows=mapping)
       d
a b c   
1 9 4  1
2 8 2  4
3 7 5  2
4 6 4  5
9 1 8  5
```